# Driving Servo Motor with Raspberry PI 4 and ServoBlaster

Tags: raspberry-pi, servo

I'm trying to drive [this DS3225 servo motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PG8M9F3) with a Raspberry Pi 4 using the [ServoBlaster software](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster).

After installing ServoBlaster, I run the following commands:

```
sudo ./servod 
echo 3=30% > /dev/servoblaster
```

I also tried to drive it with a python script using RPi.GPIO but nothing works. I hear a subtle clicking in the motor but it doesn't move at all.

I tried with other servos, and they work fine. Also, this servo works on other MCUs so it's not defective.

I tried to play with the frequency and the duty cycle duration but haven't managed to make it work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Power supply is sufficient? The rattle noise is often an indication for too little power.

Comment: Yes I'm supplying 5V from an external power supply, grounds connected together with mcu.

Comment: To clarify, other servos work on this RP4 with ServoBlaster, and this servo works on other MCUs, but this servo does not work on this RP4 with ServoBlaster?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to have the properties of a product/software *usage* question and not a *development* (or *electronic design*) one.  Something like scope or at least cheapie USB logic analyzer traces comparing the output of the pi and the apparently working signal source would start to bring it within the realm of topic.  The key is to move beyond *guessing* what is wrong to being able to say specifically "this aspect of this differs from specification" - then you have something you can (maybe) fix.

Comment: `I'm supplying 5V from an external power supply` ... this does not mean that you are supplying sufficient current .... it is as meaningless as `I'm using a blue power supply`

Comment: @jsotola I'm pretty sure voltage brings more info than color, here's the word of the day for you: "incomplete". I finally found the reason: one of the servo **WIRES** was defective! Thanks for your suggestions though!

Comment: @garys, only if the volage is measured when the power supply is powering the circuit at full load

Answer (score 1):

After running some tests on the wires themselves, I found out one of them wasn't conducting properly. I just replaced it and it now works great.